# Changing string into integer in a column using lambda function doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

In my dataset there is a column that contains yes-no values, so I want to change them into 1-yes and 0-no using lambda function.

Code:

```
df['columnname'] = df['columnname'].apply(lambda a:1 if a == 'Yes' else 0)
```

The problem is all of data in my dataset turns into 0. Where is the error?

Comment: Is very hard to say without looking at the actual data, but using apply here seems like a misuse, you could simply use `df["columname"].eq("Yes")`

Comment: can you share the dataset please? upload on drive and share link here

Comment: Don't use `apply`: `df['columnname'].eq('yes').astype(int)` or `df['columnname'].map({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})`

Comment: right, the map function seems way more reasonable, thank you

Comment: @mozway why?  both of them will eventually loop internally right?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar do the timing by yourself using `s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['yes', 'no'], size=1_000_000))`. `.eq('yes').astype(int)` is ~4.5x faster, `map` is ~6.5x faster

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Map is faster.

Comment: indeed, just verified `map` is indeed faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.replace`:

```
new_label = {'columnname': {'yes': 1, 'no': 0}}
df.replace(new_label, inplace=True)
```